# Finding out if an enum has the "Flags" attribute set

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Using reflection, how do I determine whether an enum has the Flags attribute or not

so for MyColor return true

```
[Flags]
public enum MyColor
{
    Yellow = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Red = 4,
    Blue = 8
}
```

and for MyTrade return false

```
public enum MyTrade
{
    Stock = 1,
    Floor = 2,
    Net = 4,
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are on .NET 4.5:

```
if (typeof(MyColor).GetCustomAttributes<FlagsAttribute>().Any())
{
}
```

Comment: `Type` class has no such `GetCustomAttribute<T>` method. Is this an extension method you wrote?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: why not? here for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194531.aspx, from .net 4.5

Comment: Need to add `using System.Reflection;` to have access to the extension.

Comment: A bit late, but I believe `typeof(MyColor).IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false)` is made for this. Avoids having to process a collection.

Comment: @khellang ah I did not see that one before, just thought I'd comment on the accepted answer. +1'd yours :)

Comment: The other two answers are better than this. This technically doesnt even compile now.

Answer (score 31):

```
if (typeof(MyEnum).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FlagsAttribute), false).Length > 0)
```

Answer (score 27):

If you just want to check if an attribute is present, without inspecting any attribute data, you should use [`MemberInfo.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx). It returns a `bool` that indicates "whether one or more attributes of the specified type or of its derived types is applied to this member" instead of dealing with a collection of attributes.

#### Example

```cs
typeof(MyColor).IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), inherit: false); // true
typeof(MyTrade).IsDefined(typeof(FlagsAttribute), inherit: false); // false
```

Or, if you're on .NET 4.5+:

```cs
using System.Reflection;

typeof(MyColor).IsDefined<FlagsAttribute>(inherit: false); // true
typeof(MyTrade).IsDefined<FlagsAttribute>(inherit: false); // false
```

Comment: I can't find the generic version of `IsDefined` in the documentation. Where does that come from?